# How can I clone element and append to the clone another el?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some id div with elements(classes and Ids), I need to clone it and append to my clone new class. How can I do it?

```js
window.onload = Func ();

function Func () {

var temp = document.getElementById("start");
var cl = temp.cloneNode(true);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "class";
div.innerHTML = "MyText";
var result = cl.getElementById("second").append(div);
alert(result.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
<div id="second">
<a href="#">Link</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Please show expected results and give a better explanation of what you want to accomplish. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation. See [ask] ... and... [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl, I need to get clone of ID element and at the moment when I will append some data to page I need to append the same data to my clone. Then I could compare the real page and the clone length by the innerHTML

Comment: Can do anything to a clone ... even if it's not in the dom, that you can do to an element in the dom. Still not clear where your problem is

Comment: @ charlietfl, Ok, then answer me please how can I getElementById from the clone? var result = cl.getElementById("second"); This doesn't work!

Comment: `var result = cl.querySelector("#second").appendChild(div);`

Comment: depends if you want all html from inside the clone...or just the new div html in your alert

Comment: @ charlietfl, thank you man, now that's worked, but here you can take a look at my fruitless attempts https://jsfiddle.net/k453y5tp/

Comment: Need to rewrite all this explaining exactly what it is you are trying to do. Be specific. Might even be better to start a new question because that demo has not much to do with what is in this question. Read [ask] first though

Answer (score -1):

use following code

```
$(function(){
  var $Div = $('.start').clone();
  $('.second').html($Div);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery,

```
 var clone = $("#divName");
 or var clone = $(".className")

 var secondDiv = $("#secondDiv");
 or var secondDiv = $(".secondDivClassName");
 //Or you can get the html of your second div like this:
 var myHtml = secondDiv.html(); //if you don't give any parameter, it takes the inner html of the given element.

 //and finally insert your html into the clone like this :
 clone.html(myHtml);// in this case, the html() methode takes a parameter and inserts the given parameters into the given element.
```

You should reference JQuery to your page.
Tell me if it works.

Comment: I don't need to append clone to the page. I want to append something to my clone -  var clone = $("#div"); clone.append('SomeNode');

Comment: javascript is case sensitve...`.Append()` will throw error

Comment: You can use the some logic, var content = $("#someNode"); clone.Append(content); Don't forget using the # character before the name.

Comment: I don't want to insist but, I try to explain, if you want to find an item by classname you should use this  var clone = $(".className"); and if you want to find Something by name you should use this : var clone = $("#elementName"); and finally you can call this method : clone.html('someNode')

Comment: @ Coskun Ozogul, and how then will I append node to html for id there?